# I can install Windows 10 2004 with MDT but not 21H1

Tags: windows-10, deployment, mdt, windows-10-v21h1

So the time to deploy Windows to some new laptops rolled around this year.  As 21H1 was already out, so I thought I'd spare my users a feature upgrade by installing from the 21H1 image.

I've found that I can deploy Windows 10 2004 to the same machine using the task sequence I created for that purpose last year.

However, the task sequence I created to install 21H1 always fails.  It copies the install image over to the disk, then tries to apply unattend.xml with DISM.  This results in

```
FAILURE (5627) 14081: Run DISM.exe
Litetouch deployment failed, Return Code =-2147467259 (0x80004005) 
Failed to run the action: Install Operating System
```

plus a cascade of errors that follow form the initial failure.   The smsts.log file shows, in LTIDiskPart,

```
Failed to create C:\_SMSTaskSequence Error 0x80070003
```

and later, in LTIApply,

```
Executing command line: cscript.exe "%SCRIPTROOT%\LTIApply.wsf"
Process completed with exit code 5627
Could not find CCM install folder. Don't use ccmerrors.dll
```

The machine with Deployment Workbench is running Windows 10 2004 and the deployment share is on a NAS.

I used the same steps to get a 21H1 task sequence as I used for 2004:

1. Download the ISO from VLSC.
2. Import the ISO in Deployment Workbench
3. Use DISM to mount the WIM, remove unwanted provisioned packages, and copy over the desired Start Menu/Taskbar file `LayoutModification.xml`
4. Create a task sequence
5. Select the driver selection profile
6. Change offline packages to Nothing
7. Clean up the unattend file.

Microsoft says that the 2004 ADK and MDT can be used without any modification to deploy 21H1.  The workstation with the ADK installed, and running Deployment Workbench, is running Windows 10 2004.

Comment: Need to add a new [tag:windows-10-v21h1] tag but I don't have the rep on this site to create new tags yet.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=mdt+%220x80004005%22). Most folks on this site have no experience with MDT and deploying Windows, so you may also want to copy/paste this into a question on [Spiceworks](https://community.spiceworks.com/windows/windows-10) as well since the userbase there has more experience with deploying Windows, coupled with Microsoft vendor reps who monitor the site daily and participate in troubleshooting. _(I experienced the same error years ago when deploying Windows 8.1 and know it's simple to fix, but I can't recall what the fix was.)_

Comment: @JW0914 The search results you provide point to several different possible causes and are similar to what I got when I first Googled it.  I eventually realized that feature updates via enablement package are much less painful than the old-style feature updates, so it was easier to end-run the problem by deploying 2004 and then letting the enablement package run.

Answer (score 0):

But I did successfully deploy 21H1 without any issues. Microsoft says that the 2004 ADK and MDT can be used without any modification to deploy 21H1 (This is absolutely correct as 2004 is the base image).

If you had "FAILURE (5627) 14081: Run DISM.exe", I would have easily said you should ignore it but you have got other issues. Please review your MDT settings etc and file system settings in your new deployment share.